# Difference between an optional field not being present Vs field present with null value in rest request body

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Is there a way to check if an optional field is present in request body with null value OR it is not present at all in the request body. I have a requirement where if an optional field is present with value set to null, we need an exception but if the field is not present at all, that is considered fine.

In below example operatorName is an optional field:

```
Invalid Case:
{
    "creationDateTime": "2019-10-08",
    "requestedAmount": "2499",
    "operatorPhone": "1234567890",
    "operatorName": null 
}

Valid Case:

{
    "creationDateTime": "2019-10-08",
    "requestedAmount": "2499",
    "operatorPhone": "1234567890"
}
```

Please suggest if there is a way to know if operatorName is present in the request. By default, Java sets the value to null is field is absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`.

If you are using class to map request, by default, Java sets the value to null is field is absent.

You can use `Map` to get request data instead of class and check for key,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/process", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> process(@RequestBody Map data, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    if (data.containsKey("operatorName") && null == data.get("operatorName"))
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("operatorName can not be null");
    //valid process
    return ResponseEntity.ok("success");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But won't it exclude the field in either cases? If the value is null or field itself is not present, this will exclude the field in both cases

Comment: @NOT_FOUND i have updated answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is a good suggestion @Code_Mode but doing this will completely mess up the request validation for a complex request body.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@NotNull` above the `operatorName` in your Model/Dto.